# Saving payment date and amount in database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am developing an application for a small financing company, where they can input payment amount. The date will be generated automatically. My question is, what is the best way to save those payments in MySQL, considering that some loans will be as short as 6 months, while others will be as long as 84 months?

I'm thinking about a table with 169 columns:
REC_ID as primary key,
Date1, Amt1, Date2, Amt2, etc...

But, how efficient would it be? On a 6-month loan, out of those 169 columns, only 13 would be used.

Thanks in advance for your output.

Comment: please no, several tables, joins, db normalisation, that kind of thing.

Comment: Extremlely inefficent. For everyone involved.

Answer (score 3):

Create a payment table that has a the foreign key of the loan id in it.

the payment table will look something like this

```
id|loan_id|payment_date|payment_amount
```

Have a separate table for loans that will look like

```
id|loan_amount|loan_length
```

When you need to find out how many payments have been made run a query on the payment table with the loan_id as a search parameter.

Comment: +1 It's also possible that you won't even need the id in the payment table since (loan_id, payment_date) is also a key in this table.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a gross violation of relational design paradigms, each payment and Date should probably be a its own tuple in a table with a many to one relation to the accounts table.

```
Accounts (REC_ID, other_stuff, other_stuff) Primary key(REC_ID);
Payments (REC_ID, timestampe, amt) Primary key (REC_ID, timestampe);
```

Also consider using foreign keys to enforce existence of a valid loan for each payment. And I would guess the policy would be cascade so that deletion of load and renames of loans would carry through to the Payments table.